# How to exclude a DataRow from it's collection without Deleting it from the database?

Tags: .net, ado.net

Is there a way to remove a DataRow from it's DataRowCollection *without* deleting it from the database?

I am writing a program that monitors a web site.  It uses a DataTable from a DataAdapter created with `Select * From MonitorSamples Where 1=0` to get a DataRowCollection with no actual rows in it.  The table is quite large and the monitor doesn't need the old samples, so for the sake of simplicity and efficiency, I am only getting/keeping the rows that it is working on.  (Also, *not* getting rid of these DataRows is technically a memory leak, since they will accumulate regularly over time until the program is restarted or it runs out of memory.)

As it runs periodically, it gathers data from the web site and creates new records (`Datatable.NewRow()`) which it then adds it to the DataTable's DatarowCollection (`DataTable.Add()`), which will be Inserted into the database when `Dataset.Update` is called.  In later periods, these same DataRows will also be modified and Updated back to the database.

Still later, the monitor knows that there will be no more updates for specific records, and so I would like to remove them from the DataRowCollection, **but**, not from the database.  I don't want to Delete them, I just don't want them in the dataset any longer for efficiency sake.  If I do not remove them the DataRowCollection will become filled with thousands of these unnecessary completed rows, far outnumbering the still updating active rows.

Obviously the **.Delete()** method Deletes it from the database after `.AcceptChanges()` or `.Update()`.  Unfortunately, despite numerous claims on the Internet to the contrary, the **.Remove()** method does so also only it does it immediately.  From the [MS Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datarowcollection.remove?view=netframework-4.8):

> Calling Remove is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges.

Also, I do not want to just refill the DataSet because it would be very complex for various reasons, including those not yet completed rows that the Monitor is still updating periodically.

---

Ok, so on a whim, since so many internet posts claimed that `DataRowsCollection.Remove(DataRow)` worked, I tried it.  And it worked.(!!)

So either the doc is wrong, or I am misunderstanding something here.  I will accept the first answer that can tell me what the real story is here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database doesn't get updated until DataAdapter.Update is called. I think doing a Delete on a row, then immediately calling AcceptChanges on that row, will remove all traces of the row from the DataSet's diffgram, so that if/when DataAdapter.Update is called later, nothing will be done to that row in the database.

To help in understanding, you could try calling:

```
YourDataSet.WriteXml("c:\\somefile.xml", XmlWriteMode.DiffGram)
```

after your Remove call. 
Then have a look at the resulting file. There should not be a `<diffgr:before>` entry for the Removed row.

For background info on diffgrams: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/dataset-datatable-dataview/diffgrams

From that link:

```
Note that Deleted rows will have an Original row version in the <diffgr:before> block, but there will be no annotated element in the < DataInstance > block.
```